# Is it Possible to update SQL server data using Excel Power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I just recently realise, while using Excel, it lacks on features for being able to update SQL server data through their worksheet.

I have tried using Data-->From other sources--> SQL Server data; that works like a charm but as it has limited ability (View and only get the latest data but not update).

I don’t know if this is done purposely by Microsoft as a money making schemes. 
But through my research today, I also came across PowerQuery, and It seems to do pretty much what Data add-in did escape it has few new extra features and sounds pretty advance, therefore, I was wondering if this add-in has the ability to update SQL server data using excel sheet, if so can you guys advise me to the right direction:

I came across lots of commercials products that did the job but frankly speaking, I cannot afford it.

Comment: You can update the database through Power Query, but it is not recommended. Native queries may be run multiple times, which would lead to strange or unexpected behavior (such as the same row being inserted multiple times).

Comment: Yus, I did notice multiple data being inserted, thanks for that.

Comment: There is a nice little hack for it Power BI Desktop (which is also free), containing the same Power Query engine like Excel. So you can do everything in Power BI that you can do in the Power Query-part of Excel: https://ruiromanoblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/use-power-bi-desktop-as-an-etl-tool/

Comment: Through my research, I did encounter Power BI Desktop, and looked promising but that meant learning more unnecessary stuff (specifically speaking for myself),(I knoe more knowledge is always better but I rather spend somewhere else), having said that Microsoft could have easily created a button that did an automation data update to SQL, for example software like sqlspreads. I guess it all comes down to money as if such facilities was included software such as atlas, dynamic ax would be pretty useless. I decided to create WPF application for now, but thanks for advise

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for in this space that I've seen is the Master Data Services component included in SQL Server (Business Intelligence or Enterprise Edition). This includes an nice Excel Add-In for maintaining data, a Web UI and SQL Views and Staging Tables for data integration.

It doesn't have any direct integration with Power Query, but I would let PQ dump data into Excel Tables, then copy and paste the data into Excel tables using the MDS Add-In.